# Detecting Incognito Mode on iOS 17+ Safari for Redirect Handling

Tags: security, browser, safari, ios17, incognito-mode

We are facing an issue with our product's security feature, which involves using the 'fbclid' code in the URL. On iOS 17+ Safari, especially in incognito mode, Apple has disabled link trackers, causing redirection without the code, leading to a failure in accessing our product.

To reproduce the problem, you can use the following URL in incognito mode: "https://example.com/?fbclid=123". You'll notice that the URL changes to "https://example.com/" due to Apple's tracking and fingerprinting protection.

We are looking for a reliable method to detect whether the user is browsing in incognito mode and, based on this detection, provide an alternative URL.

We have already tried using a hidden iframe and checking the redirection from the iframe, but it didn't yield the desired result.

Any suggestions or solutions on how to detect incognito mode in iOS 17+ Safari would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been maintaining a repo on GitHub to detect incognito mode using JavaScript for several years now. It works on all modern Safari versions up to the current 17.3.

https://github.com/Joe12387/detectIncognito

Comment: Wow! didn't see it yet.
I'll take a look into it soon.
Thanks!